# Skeuomorphic keys for keyboard shortcut documentation

Tags: javascript, html, css, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm writing up some documentation for the keyboard shortcuts for some software.  The documentation is in   html/css/js.  I'd like to have images (skeuomorphic?) of a `control` and `c` key instead of just having `[ctrl] + [c]`.  I have seen this done on the web, but I am not finding any solutions with my web searches.

How can I render the Control and C keys as images using HTML/CSS/JS?  I am happy to use a third party party library to achieve the effect.

Comment: If you want images, why not use images? Or are you looking for something to style the content so that it looks like most keyboards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following CSS will style text wrapped in `<kbd></kbd>` tags exactly the same as the buttons you see here at StackOverflow.

CSS

```
kbd {
    padding: .1em .6em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    color: #333;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 0 2px #fff inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 0 2px #fff inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 0 2px #fff inset;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 .1em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    line-height: 1.4;
    white-space: nowrap
}
```

HTML

```
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd><br><br>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>
```

Output

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

There are pure CSS options for creating realistic, professional-quality key cap graphics.  Google ["*keyboard key css*"](https://www.google.com/?q=keyboard%20key%20css), for a larger list, but my favorite is [KEYS.css](https://github.com/michaelhue/keyscss): it's super simple to use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="keys.css" type="text/css" />
...
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
```

renders as:

[image: rendering of Ctrl+Shift+S using KEYS.css]